# how to send variable from .php file to .js file?

Tags: 7, javascript

I hope someone is able to help me.
The problem is the following one:
1)I have module in which a assign the variable in order to send to the template file php.tpl

```
<?php
...
$testvar="Hello from alex!";
$variables['testvar'] = $testvar; 
...
?>
```

This variable can be shown in the php.tpl file like

```
<?php print $testvar?>
```

2)I have separated .js file
How can i get access to this varuiable inside .js file?

I know how it'll be if .js file is inside .php.tpl:

```
<?php
$testvar="Hello from alex!";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = '<?php print $testvar?>';
</script>
```

The problem is how to do the same if these two files .js and .php.tpl are separated?

Comment: don't blindly echo out a variable into Javascript. If there's any Javascript metacharacters (single quotes, especially), you'll introduce syntax errors. Do `var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($testvar) ?>;` which will take care of any such issues for you, regardless of the PHP var's data-type/content.

Comment: List of Drupal 7 js tips and tricks https://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/javascript-drupal-7

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should use [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in your module, there is no need to output the variable in your `.tpl.php`:

```
drupal_add_js(array('YOURMODULE' => array('testvar' => $testvar)), array('type' => 'setting'));
```

And in your JavaScript, you can the access the value in `Drupal.settings.YOURMODULE.testvar`:

```
alert(Drupal.settings.YOURMODULE.testvar);
```

Direct usage of global variables (as suggested in your code sample) is a discouraged practice in JavaScript as it [clutter the global namespace](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace). Also, if your code is triggered on page load, check the "Behaviors" section in [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) documention (the whole page is worth reading).

Answer (score 19):

In your MODULENAME.module file use the following code.

```
$testVariable = 'himanshu';
drupal_add_js(array('MODULENAME' => array('testvar' => $testVariable)), array('type' => 'setting'));
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/MODULENAME.js');
```

And in MODULENAME.js use the following one.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MODULENAME = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      alert(settings.MODULENAME.testvar);
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

In this way, you can pass your PHP variable to JavaScript, and use it.

Comment: What does the function do and when is it triggered? Why not to use directly Drupal.settings.YOURMODULE.testvar?

Answer (score 10):

For **Drupal 8**, `drupal_add_js()` was removed (it was deprecated in Drupal 7 already) => [see this for further information](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169605).

The way to send PHP information to Javascript is perfectly described [by @4k4's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/211737/74748) to a similar question.

```
return [
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#list_type' => 'ul',
  '#items' => $my_items,
  '#attributes' => ['class' => 'some_class'],
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => ['my_module/my_library'],
    'drupalSettings' => [
      'my_library' => [
        'some_variable1' => $value,        // <== Variables passed
        'another_variable' => $take_this,  // <== 
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

In JavaScript, they can be used as follows:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_library = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      alert(drupalSettings.my_library.some_variable); //alerts the value of PHP's $value

    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: Worth to mention that in the `*.libraries.yml` there also should be a dependency defined to `- core/drupalSettings`.