# Send php variable to js in drupal 8 block

Tags: theming, 8, javascript, blocks

I am trying to attach js files attach_library() inside a custom block.

However, I can neither add the libraries via block nor add a library. attach_library() does not accept variables like drupal_add_js.

Any ideas on A) how to send a php variable in the block::build() function and how to attach the library through the build() instead of the twig templates?

Answer (score 5):

This is from the documentation how to attach libraries to a render array of a block plugin and send php variables to js:

> Attaching to a render array of a Block Plugin
>
> To give another example of attaching a library to a render array, If
>   you are building a block plugin in your module, you can attach the
>   libraries to the render array in the build() function of your class
>   extending the BlockBase class (as of Drupal 8 beta 6).

```
return array(
      '#theme' => 'your_module_theme_id',
      '#someVariable' => $some_variable,
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' =>  array(
          'your_module/library_name'
        ),
      ),
    );
```

> Attaching configurable JavaScript
>
> In some cases, you may want to add JavaScript to a page that depends
>   on some computed PHP information.
>
> In this case, create a JavaScript file, define and attach a library
>   just like before, but also attach JavaScript settings and have that
>   JavaScript file read those settings, via drupalSettings (the successor
>   to Drupal 7's Drupal.settings). However, to make drupalSettings
>   available to our JavaScript file, we have to do the same work as we
>   had to do to make jQuery available: we have to declare a dependency on
>   it.
>
> So that then becomes:

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

and

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider';
$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['fluffiness']['cuddlySlider']['foo'] = 'bar';
```

https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets