# Is it possible to declare option inside drupal_add_js?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm stuck on including an external JavaScript file on a custom page. The API service requires the HTML to be formatted as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.example.com/api.js">
api_key:   [key]
</script>
```

No idea if this can be done the Drupal way. I tried:

```
// load SDK
drupal_add_js('//platform.example.com/api.js', 'external');
drupal_add_js('api_key:   [key]', 'inline');
```

But without success. The API_key declaration need to be done inside the first  tag that links to the external JS. I know you can add extra parameters like documented on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x but this case is not described.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/how-to-send-variable-from-php-file-to-js-file-in-drupal-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$external_js = array(
  '#markup' => '<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.example.com/api.js">
    api_key:   [key]
  </script>',
);

drupal_add_html_head($external_js, 'my_module');
```